# Is it okay to use a heat gun to quickly dry watercolors?

Tags: painting, watercolor

During life drawing sessions, I would like to do fast watercolors so I need a way to quickly dry my glazes. Since there are other people, I would like it to be quiet as well as fast.

Would a heat gun work?

Comment: Heat guns are often rather loud as well as fierce, but there's a smaller kind used for heatshrink sleeving.  Do you have power available?  There are a few cordless heat guns,  You'd want adjustable temperature down to quite lo to avoid scorching the paper.

Comment: A hair dryer would be better--little chance of scorching the paper.

Comment: @fixer1234 we've got the old version of [this DeWalt](https://www.dewalt.com/products/power-tools/specialty-and-other-tools/heat-gun/d26950) in work.  It goes cooler than a hair dryer, and is less likely to blow your work around.  Former colleagues have used it to dry hair, and jeans (while wearing them).  It's also quieter than a hairdryer, though still not quiet.  I'd answer with some of this info, but don't know about the effects on watercolours you might want to keep for long periods. Direct heat is fine on kids painting, though I use my fan oven set to 50°C for speed-drying kids stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I don't think there is anything to worry about.

As *fixer1234* and *Chris H* point out in the comments, be sure to keep a **low heat** setting. Like UV light and humidity, heat (**especially when concentrated and focused**) does have a negative impact on the pigments and paper, but as long as you don't go far above what can conceivably be environmental temperatures, you have nothing to worry about. After all, the history of watercolour and its preservation shows that working temperatures and normal environmental conditions don't significantly impact the longevity of artworks in that medium - they were developed to be used in these conditions.

But even *if* drying your glazes with a heat gun *was* noticeably detrimental, if that would help you enjoy your time spent painting more, and develop your skills quicker, it could easily outweigh the damage done.

Do remember that depending on the amount of water you use the **air flow** of a dryer or heat gun can also influence the lines of your brushstrokes, especially those made with pigments with higher granulation (i.e. less staining ones, see also [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/7627/6388)).

#### In short:

Keep

- a low temperature setting;
- a low air flow setting;
- moving the gun/dryer around in an even pattern.

As far as **noise** is concerned: both heat guns and hair dryers seem to produce sound of around 70 dB(A) and up, but I think it's easier to come by quieter heat guns, although it's hard to find any specs on sound levels online. Lower temps and air flows will of course produce less noise.
A quieter but less practical alternative would be a portable heater. Some of these are lightweight enough to be able to be picked up and aimed at your drawing.
You mention life drawing sessions, so I assume there is heating in the space: would it be possible to make use of those heat sources?

Comment: No, those are generally next to or on the model stand, pointed at the model.

Comment: @kevin I'm used to model drawing in old spaces, where the rooms needed to have their radiators turned all the way up in addition to the portable heaters near the models. Those old radiators were especially convenient since they were very broad and you could easily lay down some (smaller) drawings on top of them.